# search any string in list with wildcard

Tags: python, string, list, any

I have this piece of code

```
for j in range(length_termlist):    
    searchterm=''.join(termlist[j])    
    if any(searchterm in s for s in text[k]):
        do something
```

termlist is a list that contains my search terms. These i want to find in the second list (text) which contains multiple sentences. This works so far but the accuracy isn't good enough, because it finds any string combination. Now I rather would like to find the search term and a wildcard at the end for considering plural.

Example for code now: search term "car" is detected in word "carry".

How it should be: search term "car" is only detected in words "car", "cars" ..."car?" or something like that.

Is there any easy addition to my code above or is another search method necessary?

Edit: Aim in general is to find texts where the search terms appear. A little variance (ex. plural) helps to identify more text with same semantic context.

Comment: Welp, car* would match carry. If you want to detect different inflections of a word, you'd need something more powerful like NLTK.

Comment: What exactly is _"something like that"_? If you can give some more examples of words that should and shouldn't match, we might be able to figure something out. Regex looks like a good candidate for this sort of thing.

Comment: @Rawing I believe OP wants to detect different inflections of the same word, I believe regex cannot help.

Comment: obviously @coldspeed is right, i just wanted to say the last character can be different. I think therefore exist the "?"-wildcard?

Comment: @rawing To keep it easy I just want to consider any variance in matching for the plural. In most cases it would be enough, if there is a variance of one character (one additional, one missing, one different at any place...). Examples partner/partners, program/programs. To search the programming language C it should match an outstanding letter "c". So for more complexity i could imagine to match any search terms of a length about 3 characters with a variance of one unmatching character. But that's just a nice to have, considering the plural should be the basic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The re module can do this

```
regex = re.compile(r'\b%ss?\b' % re.escape(searchterm))
if any(regex.search(s) for s in text[k]) ...
```

Comment: Can you please explain what "\b%ss?\b" means?

Comment: First `r"\b%ss?\b" % 'car'` produces `"\bcars?\b"`. This is a string in the regular expression language. `\b` means that we're at the beginning or at the end of a word, and `s?` means that we accept an optional `s`. It's all in the official documentation https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html?highlight=re#regular-expression-syntax

Comment: thank you, this works fine and the results are now better :)